# Abstracting leads to a term ill-typed... yet well-typed

Tags: coq

I was stuck on a problem for a while, for which I derived a smaller standalone example:

```
Axiom f : nat -> Set.

Goal forall (n : nat) (e : n = n) (x : f n),
  match e in _ = _n return f _n -> Prop with
  | Logic.eq_refl => fun v : f n => v = x
  end x.
```

Now, if you try to `destruct e`, you get the following error message:

```
Error: Abstracting over the terms "n0" and "e" leads to a term
"fun (n0 : nat) (e : n0 = n0) =>
 forall x : f n0,
 match e in (_ = _n) return (f _n -> Prop) with
 | Logic.eq_refl => fun v : f n0 => v = x
 end x" which is ill-typed.
```

After scratching my head for a while, I couldn't figure out what was ill-typed in that term... So I tried this:

```
Definition illt :=
  fun (n : nat) (e : n = n) =>
  forall x : f n,
  match e in _ = _n return f _n -> Prop with
  | Logic.eq_refl => fun v : f n => v = x
  end x.
```

And Coq accepts it, at type `forall n : nat, n = n -> Prop`.

So, what is wrong with this error message, and how could I solve/tweak my initial goal?

---

BTW this is all coq8.3. If this is something fixed in 8.4, please tell me, and my apologies! :)

---

EDIT: To address Robin Green's comment, here is the `Set Printing All` versions of the error message:

```
Error: Abstracting over the terms "n0" and "e" leads to a term
"fun (n0 : nat) (e : @eq nat n0 n0) =>
 forall x : f n0,
 match e in (@eq _ _ _n) return (f _n -> Prop) with
 | eq_refl => fun v : f n0 => @eq (f n0) v x
 end x" which is ill-typed.
```

It is a well-typed term, and nothing is implicit.

Comment: If you enable the display of all hidden aspects you may find what is ill-typed. Unfortunately, by default, Coq does not always give you the full term it is thinking of in error messages. Try `Set Printing All.`

Comment: @RobinGreen Sure it's a good thing to do in general, but here the only implicit is the first parameter of `eq` and it does not seem to lead to ill-typedness at all...

Comment: eq actually has three parameters (the first one is the type), and the first two are implicit there.

Comment: In `(e : n = n)`, `nat` is implicit but inferrable. In `_ = _n`, the two type parameters are not to be specified, only the indices should be named. In `v = x`, `f n` is implicit but inferrable. I do not believe there is any problem with implicits here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible explanation of the problem.  What happens when constructing a pattern-matching construct can also be described using a theorem.  Here is my view of the theorem that is being used in your case.

```
Check eq_rect.

eq_rect
 : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A -> Type),
   P x -> forall y : A, x = y -> P y
```

So when pattern matching on an equality, you have to provide a formula P parametrized on **any value** `y` that happens to be provably equal to `x`.  Intuitively, you should be able to replace your pattern-matching expression by `apply eq_rect`, but the property P that should come up there is beyond the reach of what Coq can guess, because every occurrence of `x` in your formula is bound to be in type `f n` and cannot just be in type `f m` where `m = n`.  The error message does not say that, it is probably a mistake.

To perform your proof, I suggest rather to use the fact that proofs of equality are unique in certain classes of types, and `nat` belongs to such a class.  This is treated in the file Eqdep_dec.

```
Require Eqdep_dec Arith.
```

Now your proof goes through quite easily.

```
Goal forall n (x : f n) (e : n = n),
  match e in _ = _n return f _n -> Prop with
  | Logic.eq_refl => fun v : f n => v = x
  end x.
intros n x e; replace e with (eq_refl n).
  reflexivity.
apply Eqdep_dec.UIP_dec, eq_nat_dec.
Qed.
```

Now, this solution may feel unsatisfactory.  Where does this `UIP_dec` come from?  UIP stands for *uniqueness of identity proofs* and unfortunately, this property is not guaranteed for all arbitrary types.  It is guaranteed for all types where equality is decidable (as expressed by `UIP_dec`), for instance `nat`.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. I had finally given up on SO and posted on Coq Club, you might have seen it and here is the thread: https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2013-02/msg00041.html So to prove that all proofs of reflexivity are eq_refl, I used UIP proven in the case of decidable types: my actual example did not have `nat` as in here, but a type `desc` or descriptions, where `f` was a "denotation" from that description to an actual type it denotes. Your answer is nevertheless very interesting! And so is HTT, even though at the moment it is quite over my head! :)