# Coq: keeping information in a match statement

Tags: recursion, coq

I'm building a recursive function that does a `match` on a list `l`. In the `cons` branch I need to use the information that `l = cons a l'` in order to prove that the recursive function terminates.  However, when I use `match l` the information gets lost.

How can I use `match` to keep the information?

Here is the function (`drop` and `drop_lemma_le` are given at the end, for readability):

```
Fixpoint picksome (l:list nat) (H : Acc lt (length l)) {struct H}: list nat.
    refine (
        match l with
            nil => nil
          | cons a l' => cons a (picksome (drop a l') _)
        end
      ).

    apply H.
    assert (l = cons a l') by admit.  (* here is where I need the information *)
    rewrite H0.
    simpl.
    apply le_lt_n_Sm.
    apply drop_lemma_le.
Defined. (* Can't end definition here because of the 'admit'. *)
```

I am actually able to define the whole function via `refine` like below, but it is not really readable.  Doing `Print picksome.` reveals how Coq has handled the problem, but it is also quite long and unreadable with nested functions, etc.

There must be a more readable way to write it, right?

```
Fixpoint picksome (l:list nat) (H : Acc lt (length l)) {struct H}: list nat.
Proof.
  refine ( _ ).
  remember l as L.
  destruct l as [| a l'].
  apply nil.
  apply (cons a).
  apply (picksome (drop a l')).
  apply H.
  rewrite HeqL.
  simpl.
  apply le_lt_n_Sm.
  apply drop_lemma_le.
Defined.
```

My first attempt was to try something like this

```
Definition list_cons_dec {T} (l:list T) :
  {exists a l', l=a::l'} + {~ exists a l', l=a::l'}.
  remember l as L.
  destruct l as [| a l'].
  - right; subst L; intros [a [A B]]; inversion B.
  - left; exists a, l'; apply HeqL.
Defined.

Fixpoint picksome (l:list nat) (H : Acc lt (length l)) {struct H}: list nat.
Proof.
  refine (
      match list_cons_dec l with
        | right Hdec => nil
        | left Hdec => cons _ (picksome (drop _ _) _)
      end
    ).
  destruct l.
  inversion Hdec.  (* fails *)
```

I'm unable to get out the actual `a` and `l'` that `l` is made from.  Coq complains:

```
Error: Inversion would require case analysis on sort Set which is not allowed
for inductive definition ex.
```

What would be the proper (readable) way to do this?

---

Here are the definitions of `drop` and `drop_lemma_le`.

```
Fixpoint drop {T} n (l:list T) :=
  match n with
    | O => l
    | S n' => match l with
                | nil => nil
                | cons _ l' => drop n' l'
              end
  end.

Lemma drop_lemma_le : forall {T} n (l:list T), length (drop n l) <= (length l).
Proof.
  intros; generalize n;
  induction l; intros; destruct n0; try reflexivity.
  apply le_S; apply IHl.
Defined.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remember what the list you are pattern-matching on looks like, you need to simply change the return type of your match like so.

```
Fixpoint picksome (l:list nat) (H : Acc lt (length l)) {struct H}: list nat.
    refine (
        (match l as m return l = m -> list nat with
            nil       => fun Hyp => nil
          | cons a l' => fun Hyp => cons a (picksome (drop a l') _)
        end) (eq_refl l)
      ).
```

What this `match l as m return l = m -> list nat` is saying is that you are performing a pattern matching on `l`, that you'll call the matching form `m` and that, given a proof that `l` equals `m`, you'll build a list of nats.

Now, the type of the `match` block will be slightly different: instead of just delivering a `list nat`, it will deliver a function of type `l = l -> list nat`. Luckily for us, `eq_refl l` delivers a proof that `l` is equal to itself so we can apply the match to that and get back our initial `list nat`.

Looking at the branches of the match, we can see that:

- In the `nil` case, you can ignore the extra Hypothesis which you don't need.
- In the `cons` case, it provides you precisely the much needed hypothesis and you can discharge your proof obligation like so:

  ```
  apply H.
  rewrite Hyp.
  simpl.
  apply le_lt_n_Sm.
  apply drop_lemma_le.
  ```

  Defined.

Comment: Very well explained!  This must be quite a common pattern...?  Is this the most easily read way to write it? (I'm not complaining, just wondering...)

Comment: Yes it's a fairly common pattern. Especially when dealing with dependently-typed data where you need to remember what shape the indices are in the different branches to be able to dismiss some of them. E.g. [Safe head for Vector of length > 0](https://gist.github.com/gallais/aa0aaad9edbc9e361eb2) where you want to be able to say "the nil case will never happen; promise!".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lower-powered way of achieving what you want. The solution gallais offers is instructive, but trying to destruct on such complicated matches later on [may produce type errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867685/abstracting-leads-to-a-term-ill-typed-yet-well-typed?rq=3). This problem can [in turn be solved with ssreflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63027162/abstraction-typing-error-resulting-from-case-eq-and-rewriting-in-coq), and perhaps other methods, but maybe you just want the most straightforward possible solution.

```
Definition is_cons : forall ls : list nat,
   {x | ls = cons (fst x) (snd x)} + { ls = nil }.
Proof. destruct ls eqn:K. now right. now left; exists (n,l). Defined.

Fixpoint picksome (l:list nat) (H : Acc lt (length l)) {struct H}: list nat.
  refine (if is_cons l then _ else nil).     
  destruct s as [(a, l') K].
  refine (cons a (picksome (drop a l') _)).
  apply H.
  assert (l = cons a l') by auto.  (* There you go! :) *)
```

Alternatively, and even simpler, you can make use of the eqn variant of destruct. However, as `Print picksome` will show, this will generate a complex match statement with the same problems as gallais'.

```
Fixpoint picksome (l:list nat) (H : Acc lt (length l)) {struct H}: list nat.
  destruct l as [|a l'] eqn:K.
  exact nil.
  refine (cons a (picksome (drop a l') _)).
  apply H.
  (* You have access to l = cons a l' already in your context *)
```