# Using contextual information in Coq pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, coq

I want to define a function `app_1` which converts an `n`-ary function `f : X ^^ n --> Y` into a new function `f' : (Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y`, provided that there is a `z : Z` to apply once to all of its arguments. For instance,

```
Example ex1 : app_1 plus 2 S pred = 4.
trivial. Qed.
```

`app_1 plus 2` is able to take the unary functions `S` and `pred` as arguments because it applies both of them to `2` first, and then apply the results to `plus`.

Here's my attempted definition of `app_1`:

```coq
Fixpoint app_1 {X Y Z : Type} {n : nat} 
(f : X ^^ n --> Y) (z : Z) :
(Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y :=
match n return ((Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y) with
| O    => f
| S n' => fun g => app_1 (f (g z)) z
end.
```

Which doesn't work, because Coq doesn't like the clause `| O => f`, and says:

```
The term "f" has type "X ^^ n --> Y" while it is expected to have type "(Z -> X) ^^ 0 --> Y".
```

But if `n = O`, `X ^^ n --> Y = X ^^ 0 --> Y = Y = (Z -> X) ^^ 0 --> Y`, so it's not a type mismatch. The problem is that Coq can't use the contextual information `n = O` to figure out the equivalence.

Some preliminary searches show that this is a well-known problem, but it's a little confusing how to apply those discussions to this case. For instance, [an almost identical question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316254/coq-keeping-information-in-a-match-statement) is solved using `return`, which is what I (sort of) tried above as well, to no avail.

Is there a way to make this pattern match work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, you must apply the *convoy pattern* (cf. Adam Chlipala's [CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html) book) and make the pattern-matching return a *function*:

```coq
Require Import Coq.Numbers.NaryFunctions.

Fixpoint app_1 {X Y Z : Type} {n : nat}
(f : X ^^ n --> Y) (z : Z) :
(Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y :=
match n return (X ^^ n --> Y) -> ((Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y) with
| O    => fun f => f
| S n' => fun f g => app_1 (f (g z)) z
end f.
```

In order to use the information about `f`'s type, it needs to be re-abstracted: in each branch, it'll have the right type.

Answer (score 2):

You can just delay getting your arguments until after `n` has been refined:

```coq
Fixpoint app_1 {X Y Z : Type} {n : nat}
  : (X ^^ n --> Y) -> Z -> (Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y :=
  match n return (X ^^ n --> Y) -> Z -> (Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y with
    | O    => fun f _ => f
    | S n' => fun f z g => app_1 (f (g z)) z
  end.
```

By the time `f` is bound, its type has already been changed into `X ^^ 0 --> Y`, and so it works out.

EDIT: Ah, I was going to add this, but Arthur beat me to it!

```coq
Fixpoint app_1 {X Y Z : Type} {n : nat} (f: X ^^ n --> Y) (z: Z)
  : (Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y :=
  match n return X ^^ n --> Y -> ((Z -> X) ^^ n --> Y) with
    | O    => fun f => f
    | S n' => fun f' g => app_1 (f' (g z)) z
  end f.
```